# Weird python/tkinter error

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have this code:

```
from urllib2 import *
import re
import tkSimpleDialog
import os
import glob
from Tkinter import *
class App:



def __init__(self, master):



    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()




    image1 = PhotoImage(file="picture.gif")
    w = image1.width()
    h = image1.height()

    master.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))

    # tk.Frame has no image argument

    panel1 = Label(master, image=image1)
    panel1.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')

    panel1.image = image1
    self.e = Entry(frame)
    self.e.grid(row=0, column=0)



    b = Button(frame, text='Search', command=self.whale)
    b.grid(row=0, column=1)



###
def whale(self):
    page = '1'
    def newre():
        page = '1'
        pages = int(page)
        peg = pages + 1
        pege = str(peg)
        page = pege
        self.whale()
    alist = []
    mu = self.e.get()

    print mu
    mus = mu.replace(' ','-')



    op = urlopen('http://website' + mus + '-'+page+'.html')

    ops = op.read()


    if 'charset="utf-8">var playlist' in ops:
        print 'yes'
        cal = ops.split('charset="utf-8">var playlist',1)
        del cal[0]
        cv = str(cal)
        cals = cv.split('},];</script><div',1)
        del cals[1]


    cals = str(cals)
    v = cals.replace('{', '''

    ''')


    vn = v.replace('[','')
    vnm = vn.replace(']','')

    parsed = re.findall('author : "([^"]+)",title : "([^"]+)",type : "([^"]+)",file : "([^"]+)",id : "([^"]+)', vnm)
    print mus
    cvb0 = ','.join(map(''.join,parsed[0]))
    cvb1 = ','.join(map(''.join,parsed[1]))
    cvb2 = ','.join(map(''.join,parsed[2]))
    cvb3 = ','.join(map(''.join,parsed[3]))
    cvb4 = ','.join(map(''.join,parsed[4]))
    cvb5 = ','.join(map(''.join,parsed[5]))
    cvb6 = ','.join(map(''.join,parsed[6]))
    cvb7 = ','.join(map(''.join,parsed[7]))
    cvb8 = ','.join(map(''.join,parsed[8]))
    cvb9 = ','.join(map(''.join,parsed[9]))


    canada0 = cvb0.split('sound,',1)
    canada1 = cvb1.split('sound,',1)
    canada2 = cvb2.split('sound,',1)
    canada3 = cvb3.split('sound,',1)
    canada4 = cvb4.split('sound,',1)
    canada5 = cvb5.split('sound,',1)
    canada6 = cvb6.split('sound,',1)
    canada7 = cvb7.split('sound,',1)
    canada8 = cvb8.split('sound,',1)
    canada9 = cvb9.split('sound,',1)

    song0 = canada0[0]

    song1 = canada1[0]
    song2 = canada2[0]
    song3 = canada3[0]
    song4 = canada4[0]
    song5 = canada5[0]
    song6 = canada6[0]
    song7 = canada7[0]
    song8 = canada8[0]
    song9 = canada9[0]

    del canada0[0]
    del canada1[0]
    del canada2[0]
    del canada3[0]
    del canada4[0]
    del canada5[0]
    del canada6[0]
    del canada7[0]
    del canada8[0]
    del canada9[0]

    run0 = str(canada0)
    run1 = str(canada1)
    run2 = str(canada2)
    run3 = str(canada3)
    run4 = str(canada4)
    run5 = str(canada5)
    run6 = str(canada6)
    run7 = str(canada7)
    run8 = str(canada8)
    run9 = str(canada9)


    #run0
    runs0 = str(run0)
    nun0 = runs0.split(',',1)
    del nun0[1]
    nun0 = str(nun0)
    run0 = nun0.replace('[','')
    runs0 = run0.replace(']','')
    runss0 = runs0.replace('"','')
    runsss0 = runss0.replace("'",'')
    #run1
    runs1 = str(run1)
    nun1 = runs1.split(',',1)
    del nun1[1]
    nun1 = str(nun1)
    run1 = nun1.replace('[','')
    runs1 = run1.replace(']','')
    runss1 = runs1.replace('"','')
    runsss1 = runss1.replace("'",'')
    #run2
    runs2 = str(run2)
    nun2 = runs2.split(',',1)
    del nun2[1]
    nun2 = str(nun2)
    run2 = nun2.replace('[','')
    runs2 = run2.replace(']','')
    runss2 = runs2.replace('"','')
    runsss2 = runss2.replace("'",'')
    #run3
    runs3 = str(run3)
    nun3 = runs3.split(',',1)
    del nun3[1]
    nun3 = str(nun3)
    run3 = nun3.replace('[','')
    runs3 = run3.replace(']','')
    runss3 = runs3.replace('"','')
    runsss3 = runss3.replace("'",'')
    #run4
    runs4 = str(run4)
    nun4 = runs4.split(',',1)
    del nun4[1]
    nun4 = str(nun4)
    run4 = nun4.replace('[','')
    runs4 = run4.replace(']','')
    runss4 = runs4.replace('"','')
    runsss4 = runss4.replace("'",'')
    #run5
    runs5 = str(run5)
    nun5 = runs5.split(',',1)
    del nun5[1]
    nun5 = str(nun5)
    run5 = nun5.replace('[','')
    runs5 = run5.replace(']','')
    runss5 = runs5.replace('"','')
    runsss5 = runss5.replace("'",'')
    #run6
    runs6 = str(run6)
    nun6 = runs6.split(',',1)
    del nun6[1]
    nun6 = str(nun6)
    run6 = nun6.replace('[','')
    runs6 = run6.replace(']','')
    runss6 = runs6.replace('"','')
    runsss6 = runss6.replace("'",'')
    #run7
    runs7 = str(run7)
    nun7 = runs7.split(',',1)
    del nun7[1]
    nun7 = str(nun7)
    run7 = nun7.replace('[','')
    runs7 = run7.replace(']','')
    runss7 = runs7.replace('"','')
    runsss7 = runss7.replace("'",'')
    #run8
    runs8 = str(run8)
    nun8 = runs8.split(',',1)
    del nun8[1]
    nun8 = str(nun8)
    run8 = nun8.replace('[','')
    runs8 = run8.replace(']','')
    runss8 = runs8.replace('"','')
    runsss8 = runss8.replace("'",'')
     #run9
    runs9 = str(run9)
    nun9 = runs9.split(',',1)
    del nun9[1]
    nun9 = str(nun9)
    run9 = nun9.replace('[','')
    runs9 = run9.replace(']','')
    runss9 = runs9.replace('"','')
    runsss9 = runss9.replace("'",'')

    def download0():
        print 'downloading...'
        url = runsss0
        down = urlopen(url)
        filepath = 'C:\Users\Psao\Desktop\whalewhire\Downloaded\ ' + song0 + '.mp3'
        local = open(filepath, "wb")
        local.write(down.read())
        print 'done'

    def download1():
        print 'downloading...'
        url = runsss1
        down = urlopen(url)
        filepath = 'C:\Users\Psao\Desktop\whalewhire\Downloaded\ ' + song1 + '.mp3'
        local = open(filepath, "wb")
        local.write(down.read())
        print 'done'

    def download2():
        print 'downloading...'
        url = runsss2
        down = urlopen(url)
        filepath = 'C:\Users\Psao\Desktop\whalewhire\Downloaded\ ' + song2 + '.mp3'
        local = open(filepath, "wb")
        local.write(down.read())
        print 'done'

    def download3():
        print 'downloading...'
        url = runsss3
        down = urlopen(url)
        filepath = 'C:\Users\Psao\Desktop\whalewhire\Downloaded\ ' + song3 + '.mp3'
        local = open(filepath, "wb")
        local.write(down.read())
        print 'done'
    def download4():
        print 'downloading...'
        url = runsss4
        down = urlopen(url)
        filepath = 'C:\Users\Psao\Desktop\whalewhire\Downloaded\ ' + song4 + '.mp3'
        local = open(filepath, "wb")
        local.write(down.read())
        print 'done'

    def download5():
        print 'downloading...'
        url = runsss5
        down = urlopen(url)
        filepath = 'C:\Users\Psao\Desktop\whalewhire\Downloaded\ ' + song5 + '.mp3'
        local = open(filepath, "wb")
        local.write(down.read())
        print 'done'

    def download6():
        print 'downloading...'
        url = runsss6
        down = urlopen(url)
        filepath = 'C:\Users\Psao\Desktop\whalewhire\Downloaded\ ' + song6 + '.mp3'
        local = open(filepath, "wb")
        local.write(down.read())
        print 'done'

    def download7():
        print 'downloading...'
        url = runsss7
        down = urlopen(url)
        filepath = 'C:\Users\Psao\Desktop\whalewhire\Downloaded\ ' + song7 + '.mp3'
        local = open(filepath, "wb")
        local.write(down.read())
        print 'done'

    def download8():
        print 'downloading...'
        url = runsss8
        down = urlopen(url)
        filepath = 'C:\Users\Psao\Desktop\whalewhire\Downloaded\ ' + song8 + '.mp3'
        local = open(filepath, "wb")
        local.write(down.read())
        print 'done'

    def download9():
        print 'downloading...'
        url = runsss9
        down = urlopen(url)
        filepath = 'C:\Users\Psao\Desktop\whalewhire\Downloaded\ ' + song9 + '.mp3'
        local = open(filepath, "wb")
        local.write(down.read())
        print 'done'
    def replay():
        Admin.destroy()
        os.system('WhaleWire.py')
    def library():


        path = 'C:\Users\Psao\Desktop\whalewhire\Downloaded'
        aw=[]





        for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path,'*.mp3') ):


            libr = infile.split('Downloaded',1)


            aw.append('\n')
            aw.append(infile)





        la = Label(Admin,width=100,height=50, text=aw).grid(row=0,column=7)

        b2s = Button(Admin,text='Search', command=replay).grid(row=0,column=8)





    print song1
    Label(Admin, text=song0).grid(row=1)
    Label(Admin, text=song1).grid(row=2)
    Label(Admin, text=song2).grid(row=3)
    Label(Admin, text=song3).grid(row=4)
    Label(Admin, text=song4).grid(row=5)
    Label(Admin, text=song5).grid(row=6)
    Label(Admin, text=song6).grid(row=7)
    Label(Admin, text=song7).grid(row=8)
    Label(Admin, text=song8).grid(row=9)
    Label(Admin, text=song9).grid(row=10)


    b0 = Button(Admin, text='Download', command=download0)       
    b1 = Button(Admin, text='Download', command=download1)    
    b2 = Button(Admin, text='Download', command=download2)       
    b3 = Button(Admin, text='Download', command=download3)       
    b4 = Button(Admin, text='Download', command=download4)       
    b5 = Button(Admin, text='Download', command=download5)       
    b6 = Button(Admin, text='Download', command=download6)       
    b7 = Button(Admin, text='Download', command=download7)       
    b8 = Button(Admin, text='Download', command=download8)       
    b9 = Button(Admin, text='Download', command=download9)
    b10 = Button(Admin, text='More results', command=newre)
    b11 = Button(Admin, text='Library', command=library)



    b0.grid(row=1, column=1)
    b1.grid(row=2, column=1)
    b2.grid(row=3, column=1)
    b3.grid(row=4, column=1)
    b4.grid(row=5, column=1)
    b5.grid(row=6, column=1)
    b6.grid(row=7, column=1)
    b7.grid(row=8, column=1)
    b8.grid(row=9, column=1)
    b9.grid(row=10, column=1)
    b10.grid(row=10, column=2)
    b11.grid(row=11, column=3)



Admin = Tk()
Admin.title('WhaleWires')

app = App(Admin)
Admin.mainloop()
```

I know it's really long and really repetitive, but i don't want to take the time to find a clean code for each thing.

Any way when I type in a song under two words it give me an error that vary of

```
an Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Psao\Desktop\whalewhire\WhaleWire.py", line 93, in whale
    cvb7 = ','.join(map(''.join,parsed[7]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

but the parse[#] is somtimes diffrent

any help and also if you know any code that would shorten my code I would be greatful.

Comment: first thing you can do is refactor your code. For example, your downloadX functions are all the same except they have different url and song. So define download to have parameters url and song. And call download with those params.

Comment: "I know its really long and really repetitive but i dint want to take the time to find a clean code for each thing." Sounds like it's not saving you time this way ;)

Answer (score 1):

it seems that `parsed` is some times shorter than 10 items

the 0-9 variables should be in a list rather than as individual variables this would allow one to use a loop to repeat the same actions on the values rather than duplicating the code for each variable